# How to implement ACLs (Access Control List ) in ASP.NET Core 8.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authorization, user-roles

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core 8.0 application and I need to implement Access Control Lists (ACLs) to manage user access rights. Currently, I'm using policies to check if the user's roles have permission for the resource being accessed. However, I'm wondering if my approach is correct or if there's a better way to do it.

Here's what I'm currently doing:

1. Add Permission

   ```
   {
       "id": 1,
       "resource": "api/Resources/Endpoints", // or "api/Resources/Endpoints/:id"...
       "method": "get" // or "post",...
   }
   ```
2. Add permissions to role
3. Add roles to user
4. Get role from JWT claims to check permission resource

I have this in `Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ACLs", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(async context =>
        {
            var canAccess = false;
            var httpContext = context.Resource as HttpContext;

            // get method
            var method = httpContext.Request.Method.ToString();
            // get endpoint /api/controller/...
            var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();
            var routePattern = (endpoint as RouteEndpoint)?.RoutePattern;
            var endpointValue = "";

            // convert endpoint from /api/{id}/... to /api/:id to match resource in permission
            if (routePattern != null)
            {
                endpointValue = routePattern.RawText;
            }

            if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // get dbContext from httpContext
                var dbContext = httpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<Context>();
                // get roleClaims and check role can access endpoint
                var roleClaims = httpContext.User.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == ClaimTypes.Role);

                foreach (var claim in roleClaims)
                {
                    if (canAccess)
                        break;

                    var roleName = claim.Value;
                    var roleEntity = dbContext.roles.Include(role => role.Permissions).FirstOrDefault(role => role.Name == roleName);

                    foreach (var permission in roleEntity.Permissions)
                    {
                        if (permission.Resource == StringConverter.ConvertToColonFormat(endpointValue) && MethodConverter.ConvertToString(permission.Method).ToLower() == method.ToLower())
                        {
                            canAccess = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return canAccess;
        }));
});
```

In the controller:

[image]

I'm unsure if this approach is the most efficient or if there are better practices for implementing ACLs in ASP.NET Core 8.0. I would appreciate any guidance, insights, or alternative approaches that the community can offer.

Thank you.

Comment: This ACLs thing can be a big thing. You need to identify what you want to control using ACLs. Do you have system wide actions, screen wise ACLs etc. Then thing can be answered. As far as i'm assuming by your post you need the role to have the access and based on that your UI will render. is that right? What are you using at the front?